# pass emoji unicode from cpp core-level to ios ui level

Tags: c++, ios, unicode

In c++ level I want to change emoji string like `":smile:"` to unicode `"\u{1f604}"` which ios supported.

However, C++ doesn't support that type, `\u` must follow with digit. Then I change unicode to `"\\u{1f604}"`. Now, it can work well in c++ level, but when I pass this string to ios level, ios won't change this string to emoji automatically.

Could you please give me some ideas?

I am sorry that I didn't describe it clearly.

In my project, I parse json from server in C++ level and then I pass this data to IOS level.

Comment: Probably you can have a check in your iOS code whether string starts with or contains `\\u{1f604}`, consider single slash `\u{1f604}`.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a different way of representing the same character?  So what you need in C++ may be "\u15604".  OTOH, the emoji is outside the basic multilingual plane, so if you are using UTF16, you may need to encode it as a surrogate pair.

Answer (score 2):

To escape code points above U+FFFF in C++, you have to use `\U` followed by eight hex digits (requires C++11 or later). Depending on the desired encoding, you can use one of the following string literal forms:

```
u8"\U0001f604"  // UTF-8, type const char[]
u"\U0001f604"   // UTF-16, type const char16_t[]
U"\U0001f604"   // UTF-32, type const char32_t[]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an NSString class method that takes an NSInteger containing a code point as its argument and returns an NSString* with a single Unicode character containing that code point.

To implement this, if the codePoint is <= 0xffff then translate it into a single unichar, otherwise convert it to an array of two unichar's, one high surrogate and one low surrogate (Google for explanation). Then use one of the existing NSString methods to convert this to NSString.

Conversion codepoint to high/low surrogate: Subtract 0x10000. High surrogate = 0xd800 + (code point >> 10); low surrogate = 0xdc00 + (code point & 0x3ff).

Example:

```
NSString* smile = [NSString stringWithCodePoint:0x1f604];
```